# Can I increase the longevity of fresh cut flowers with bleach?

Tags: biology, consumer-products

[This Reader's Digest article](http://www.rd.com/home/12-smart-ways-to-use-bleach/) says:

> **Increase cut flowers’ longevity** Freshly cut flowers will stay fresh longer if you add 1/4 teaspoon bleach per quart (1 liter) of vase water. Another popular recipe calls for 3 drops bleach and 1 teaspoon sugar in 1 quart (1 liter) water. This will also keep the water from getting cloudy and inhibit the growth of bacteria.

Is there any proof? I would imagine bleach would be toxic to flowers.

Comment: My wife also adds a penny; apparently the copper helps in some fashion.  Note that tap water has some minor amount of chlorine in it already to kill microorganisms.

Comment: The amount of chlorine in tap water depends heavily on your water source. I was also under the (possibly incorrect) assumption that if you left tap water to sit uncovered overnight, the chlorine would evaporate out of it. @Bryce, [Copper is a antimicrobial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimicrobial_properties_of_copper) but who knows how much is required for a significant effect.

Comment: This might also be an appropriate question over at [Gardening & Landscaping](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**Scientific American:**](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=fact-or-fiction-vodka-citrus-sodas-keep-flowers-fresh)

> [...] while water and sugar keep the flowers fresh, this mixture also
> encourages bacterial growth, which can harm the flowers.
>
> "*So **add
> bleach***," says [Susan Han](http://www.umass.edu/psis/personnel/han.html), a professor in the plant, soil and insect science department at the *University of Massachusetts Amherst*.
>
> **A little bleach kills the bacteria without damaging
> the flowers.**

[**The Royal Society of Chemistry:**](http://media.rsc.org/In%20Search%20of%20Solutions/ISOSact48.pdf)

> Bleach kills bacteria.
>
> **The flower stems have water channels. Bacteria clog up these channels - the bleach kills the bacteria.**

[**University of Nebraska:**](http://lancaster.unl.edu/hort/youth/flowertips.htm)

> The acidity of the lemon-lime soda or vinegar lowers the pH of the water so bacteria don't grow well; **the chlorine bleach kills bacteria on the stems** and the sugar provides food for the flower.

**More:**

- [NC State University - Add Hours to Your Flowers](http://www.ces.ncsu.edu/depts/hort/consumer/quickref/flowers/add_hours.html)
- [University of California - Extending the Freshness of Cut Flowers at Home](http://anrcatalog.ucdavis.edu/pdf/8113.pdf)

Comment: __Note:__ Click the links to learn _how much_ bleach should be used